# What solutions exist for retaining all files on file server (despite any deletions/changes)?

Tags: file-server, archive

I am looking for some way to archive all files on our network drive.  The files that would be retained are on a single volume on a single file server, which is currently about 800 gigs total.  I would like to be able to retain a copy of every file even after it is deleted.  If a file is modified, I would like to have every version of the file.  All of this would preferably be indexed and searchable.

This wouldn't be like a normal "archiving" solution out there in that I don't want old files removed from our main file server.  I'd want the file server to remain the same, and have a separate copy stored somewhere else (separate disk, server, etc.).  This can be thought of as a solution for legal discovery purposes.  Does anyone know if there is anything that exists out there that would do this?

UPDATE: The file server is Windows Server 2008 R2.  There's probably about 10 TB free that we could use for this, but we are able to add on additional storage as necessary, and I know storage will have to be worked into whatever option we go with.

Comment: What OS is the file server?

Comment: How much storage space can you provide for this? Given your description I think you need to be looking at many petabytes as a minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symantec Enterprise Vault is one.  As mentioned by others, you will need disk space.  It does do deduplication so it reduces needed space somewhat.

Comment: This is a very good suggestion.

Comment: That was one of the products I was checking out.  We currently use Backup Exec and CPS, so I was thinking of possibly just archiving what CPS takes off of the file server.  Do you know if Enterprise Vault can archive everything on a volume and not remove the files from the original location?  If so, how does it handle an update to a file?

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer as its the closest one provided, but I'd love to get an answer to my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you're actually doing this for eDiscovery purposes, then buy an eDiscovery product. If you're dealing with lawyers and legal matters, don't try to homegrow it.

Comment: That's definitely what I've been looking into.  Do you have any suggestions you've had any experience with?

Comment: Disclaimer - I work for Iron Mountain. We have products in this space, but we're not the only company that does.

Answer (score 0):

If your enterprise got the budget ressources for it, have a look at EMC2 storage solutions.